# how rebasing make sure to include all required dependencies?

Tags: git, version-control

I'm new to Git, just a question on how rebasing make sure to include all required dependencies. Below is the pictures from Pro Git book:
[image]

and then issue command:

> $ git rebase --onto master server client

the result is:
[image]

Here is my question:

Let's say `C3` contain a library which is called `lib.o` and the code file in `C8` just use this library, since `C8` also contains `lib.o`, the diff/patch doesn't include `lib.o`, so when we do rebasing to replay diff on the master branch. the master branch won't contain `lib.o`, so the client feature won't work on the master branch, so what's the point to do rebasing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You explicitly told it not to include anything currently in `server`'s history in the rebase, so it didn't.

```
git rebase master client
```

is how you ask Git to rebase `client` onto `master` and ~do the right thing~, i.e.   include everything that's not already in the `master` history, everything that might constitute "required dependencies", in the rebase.

In fact, the ordinary `git rebase` command is

```
git rebase
```

because ordinarily you're rebasing what you're working on and you're rebasing it on its usual upstream.  Spend more time with the actual Git docs, they tell you this stuff and don't clutter it up with a lot of distracting repetitiveness.